# Spring Boot with JSF Bean

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, spring-boot

I try to have a project with Spring Boot and JSF. I add a servlet mapping like this :

```
@ComponentScan()
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    app.setShowBanner(false);
    app.run(args);
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    FacesServlet servlet = new javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet();
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/faces/*");
}
}
```

This is my index.xhtml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<h:form>
    <p><h:outputText value="#{userView.value}"/></p>
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

My JSF bean :

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "userView")
public class UserView {

private String  value   = "This editor is provided by PrimeFaces";

public UserView() {
    super();
    System.out.println("userView");
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("---------");
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

}
```

I have added the faces-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2">
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

But spring don't managed my JSF bean, can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Your JSF bean is a JSF managed bean not a spring bean. So spring will never manage it. I would map the `FacesServlet` to `*.xhtml`. What is the problem you are experiencing? Please add the imports to the `UserView`. Finally annotate your class with `@Configuration`.

Comment: You are right, spring will not managed my bean, but my issue is that my <h:outputText value="#{userView.value}"/> is not interpreted, and my userView is not created (my System.out.println are not printed). So my JSF page don't have jsf backing bean. This is my import of userView import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

Comment: As I mentioned try to map your `FacesServlet` to `*.xhtml` instead of `/faces/*`. Your xhtml pages have to pass through/have to be rendered by the `FacesServlet`. So if you directly access them (and it isn't under `/faces/` it will not be processed but printed as is.

Comment: And as also mentioned add `@Configuration` to your class, I would expect your current config for your `FacesServlet` to be ignored.