# Spring Boot Jsf/Primefaces doesn´t work

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, spring-boot

Moin (Hello),

my english is not the best but i try it (please forgive me for Language exceptions)

I try to start a Spring Boot JSF example but i need help!
I read the post [spring-boot-and-jsf-primefaces-richfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544214/spring-boot-and-jsf-primefaces-richfaces)

my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    {
        exclude module: 'spring-webmvc'
    }

    compile "com.sun.faces:jsf-api:2.2.6"
    compile "com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:2.2.6"

    compile "org.primefaces.extensions:primefaces-extensions:1.2.1"
    compile "org.primefaces:primefaces:4.0"

    compile "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"
    compile "javax.el:el-api:2.2"
    compile "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"
    compile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
```

### }

my Application.main:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class, DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }
}
```

---

my JsfConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class JsfConfig {

    @Bean
    public FacesServlet facesServlet() {
        return new FacesServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistration() {

        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(facesServlet(), "*.xhtml");
        registration.setName("FacesServlet");
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(new ConfigureListener());
    }

    @Bean
    public ELResolver elResolver() {
        return new SpringBeanFacesELResolver();
    }

//    @Bean
//    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
//        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
//        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
//        resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
//        return resolver;
//    }
}
```

When i will start the follow exception comes:

```
2014-06-21 13:57:18.034  INFO 25888 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on Psy-World with PID 25888 (C:\Users\Psy\Psy\ws_wefaver_one_project\jsftest\bin started by Psy)
2014-06-21 13:57:18.081  INFO 25888 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@226a82c4: startup date [Sat Jun 21 13:57:18 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-06-21 13:57:18.659  INFO 25888 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2014-06-21 13:57:18.956  INFO 25888 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2014-06-21 13:57:19.114  INFO 25888 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2014-06-21 13:57:19.114  INFO 25888 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
2014-06-21 13:57:19.364  INFO 25888 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-06-21 13:57:19.364  INFO 25888 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1298 ms
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 18 more
2014-06-21 13:57:19.426  INFO 25888 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'FacesServlet' to [*.xhtml]
2014-06-21 13:57:19.442 ERROR 25888 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean.onStartup(ServletRegistrationBean.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:214)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2014-06-21 13:57:19.442 ERROR 25888 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:25)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2014-06-21 13:57:19.442  INFO 25888 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/Psy/Psy/ws_wefaver_one_project/jsftest/bin/, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.0.0.RELEASE/4f5cdb14cc71f6a27ebee380e45c6d50171c4039/spring-boot-starter-web-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.2.6/801410df866e58567ac715139c87770372272617/jsf-api-2.2.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.6/edbad76cf62d00f02ccd6804d6dabed6dbae0461/jsf-impl-2.2.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.primefaces.extensions/primefaces-extensions/1.2.1/c86508fca8ff188356c40a105c98009e1fdeed45/primefaces-extensions-1.2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.primefaces/primefaces/4.0/9084cd23acd33ea4ef4eadbcb8788a22af361c07/primefaces-4.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2/74aca283cd4f4b4f3e425f5820cda58f44409547/jstl-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.el/el-api/2.2/42971279cc8ba864462580c7fc2199fd5715ee7f/el-api-2.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/5959582d97d8b61f4d154ca9e495aafd16726e34/servlet-api-2.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/f6f66e966c70a83ffbdb6f17a0919eaf7c8aca7f/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/138d28200d97f4affe9ccaa47fab54718b438319/spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.0.3.RELEASE/41eabd53fd4ba5ba2b2d8af6c256a3741f65c2f3/spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.0.3.RELEASE/dcedf5329d7092d66cc9d2496687a5f29d883eb6/spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.0.3.RELEASE/40b25b3a693cb4cc382ddf2e69ff1b29c75a2e7d/spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.0.3.RELEASE/782a71a312dc307fa531023aa66247b9b4a109d/spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.0.0.RELEASE/461ddc5ef5a5adf6e5990157f900b2ada55add06/spring-boot-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.0.0.RELEASE/7cec92f5ac713c845d39383cab089a3ab557b088/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.6/562424e36df3d2327e8e9301a76027fca17d54ea/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.6/ab1648fe1dd6f1e5c2ec6d12f394672bb8c1036a/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.6/322e2af1694ccc75d33f4d11216c852121d8fefd/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.6/a6a9bc4e71ba7b490235a8f2294ec7dd03bf370b/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.1.1/6d9866eb3f38b66530d7b1d41526228df3e9d963/logback-core-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/19e1e2be2670b33c5dcc835550527028dddddcd1/logback-classic-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.0.0.RELEASE/95840eb7722f3f2dad7eb2805f7c2ad61940a28f/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.0.0.RELEASE/ebd1abd9fd0cb37115631cd504b86723859cc831/spring-boot-starter-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/73cbb494a912866c4c831a178c3a2a9169f4eaad/snakeyaml-1.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.52/b4afc2f8e00a43c8dd6bb289473ad1c30de59909/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/7.0.52/d5376b041a0c56c4d7e6c21d91ce9add9cb0283c/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.52.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/7.0.52/3c81b2aee6d0c6d2eafa18ad9c7c9144d302c675/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.52.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.0.0.RELEASE/592acb86bb452d54427f8a575b19c0c0f8fb166e/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.3.0/f5e853a20b60758922453d56f9ae1e64af5cb3da/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.3.2/559b70ac8a0d5cad611da4223137a920147201ba/jackson-core-2.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.3.2/c75edc740a6d8cb1cef6fa82fa594e0bce561916/jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.0.3.RELEASE/4d5066f31ea4b9c58957bf8c0c213b13ed44c1c5/spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.3.RELEASE/d6fd9778619ab87a41ae3aa879a53ee60f160c08/spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.4/a60a5e993c98c864010053cb901b7eab25306568/gson-2.2.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Psy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1/905075e6c80f206bbe6cf1e809d2caa69f420c76/commons-lang3-3.1.jar]
```

Please can everyone help me to let start the Tomcat?
I try it whitout xml, when i put the web.xml and faces-config.xml to the WEB-INF folder, i became the same exception. (I take the xml files from the post i have linked)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to add

```
compile group: "org.apache.tomcat.embed", name: "tomcat-embed-core", version:     
compile group: "org.apache.tomcat.embed", name: "tomcat-embed-logging-juli", version: tomcatVersion
compile group: "org.apache.tomcat.embed", name: "tomcat-embed-jasper", version: tomcatVersion
```

to your gradle.build