# Using JSF in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-boot

How to use JSF as a view engine in spring boot web application? Most of the references I found xml configuration but I want to make it through java annotation. How can it be done? Does JSF require xml configuration in Spring Boot Web Application?

Comment: JSF is not a view technology at all. It's a full fledged MVC framework. So your question doesn't make sense. I guess you need to carefully read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18744910

Comment: I guess you are asking how to set up the JSF  servlet in Spring Boot and map some paths to it (as a replacement or complement for Spring MVC). It took me some struggling, but in the end [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25509937/1199132) helped me have it working.