# javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean vs javax.annotation.ManagedBean integration with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-boot

What are differences between `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` vs `javax.annotation.ManagedBean`? Specifically which one can be used with annotations like `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` or `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`? I see that there are questions like:

1. [Java EE 6 @javax.annotation.ManagedBean vs. @javax.inject.Named vs. @javax.faces.ManagedBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces)
2. [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named)
3. [Why are there different bean management annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057564/why-are-there-different-bean-management-annotations)
4. [Spring boot with JSF (2.2) managed bean is not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292456/spring-boot-with-jsf-2-2-managed-bean-is-not-created)

But they are not completely answering my question! I'm using spring boot but just using `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` my bean is recognised and created successfully and also `@ViewScoped` beans are not working properly and are never destroyed!

Comment: @estebanrincon You are right. I had studied that question too, but I did not find my answer there! however I edited and narrowed my question title!

Comment: Well one thing is for sure, when mixing different @xxx could result to weird behavior, just as you are mentioning about the `@ViewScoped`..