# Using Spring Boot with JSF Beans

Tags: jsf, spring-boot

I'm trying to get Spring Boot to work with JSF. The FacesServlet is initialized and the website correctly rendered with Primefaces. But at the point where I call a JSF- or Spring-Bean, nothing is shown.

I know that this question was multiple times asked, but none of them solved my problem. After hours of searching, i don't get it to work. Am I missing something?

**Setup:**

- Spring Boot 1.2.7
- Primefaces 5.2
- JSF 2.2

**What I tried:**

- [Integrate Jsf Spring Boot Tutorial](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/037-integrate-jsf-spring-boot/)
- [Spring Boot and JSF/Primefaces/Richfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544214/spring-boot-and-jsf-primefaces-richfaces)
- [Spring Boot with JSF; Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479986/spring-boot-with-jsf-could-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces-context-face)

**What I have**

*Application.java*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public FacesServlet facesServlet() {
    return new FacesServlet();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new   ServletRegistrationBean(facesServlet(), new String[] { "*.xhtml" });
    registration.setName("FacesServlet");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return registration;
}

@Configuration
static class ConfigureJSFContextParameters implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX", ".xhtml");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    }
}

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(new ConfigureListener());
}
}
```

*JsfBean.java*

```
@ManagedBean
public class JsfBean {

private String welcomeMessage = "Populated by JSF created bean";

public String getWelcomeMessage() {
    return welcomeMessage;
}
}
```

*SpringBean.java*

```
@Component
public class SpringBean {

private String welcomeMessage = "Populated by spring created bean";

public String getWelcomeMessage() {
    return welcomeMessage;
}
}
```

*index.xhtml*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" encoding="UTF-8">

<html>
    <h:head>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h1>Rechnung</h1>
        <h3>#{springBean.welcomeMessage}</h3>
        <h3>#{jsfBean.welcomeMessage}</h3>
    </h:body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

**Output**

```
<h1>Rechnung</h1>
<h3></h3>
<h3></h3>
```

Comment: Mixing technologies like JSF and any Spring project will mostly result in a mess. I think it would be better to stick with a full ``JavaEE`` stack or completely switch to ``Spring``.

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt I heard of that problem before but I will consider this way as the last step. I still have a bit hope to do it like I described it above ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it to work. I overlooked in the linked tutorial, that I have to put the `faces-config.xml` in the resources-folder `src/main/resources/META-INF/` instead of `src/main/webapp/META-INF/`.

This led to the problem that the el-resolver never was used and this explains, why `#{springBean.welcomeMessage}` has shown nothing.

*faces-config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
          version="2.2">

<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver> 
</application>

<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingPhaseListenerMulticaster</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```